# How to allow exceptional value in Joi?

Tags: javascript, json, validation, object, joi

I am trying to validate a key in json object which should have value greater than another key's value. As exception I want to allow `-1` also to be valid value.

```
// valid because max is greater than min
var object1 = {
    min: 5,
    max: 7
}

// invalid because max is not greater than min
var object2 = {
    min: 5,
    max: 5
}

// invalid because max is not greater than min
var object3 = {
    min: 5,
    max: 3
}

// valid as exception we want to allow -1
var object4 = {
    min: 5,
    max: -1
}

var schema = Joi.object({
    min: Joi.number().integer(),
    max: Joi.number().integer().greater(Joi.ref('min'))                   
})
```

This schema is handling all case well except the exceptional case. how can I enhance my `schema` to cover exceptional case also.

Comment: max can be -1 or min can be -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `allow(-1)` to your max schema to allow the -1 value.

```
var schema = Joi.object({
    min: Joi.number().integer(),
    max: Joi.number().integer().allow(-1).greater(Joi.ref('min'))
});
```

[Ref Docs](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/?v=16.1.7#anyallowvalues)

Tests:

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');
const assert = require('assert');

var schema = Joi.object({
    min: Joi.number().integer(),
    max: Joi.number().integer().allow(-1).greater(Joi.ref('min'))
});

// valid because max is greater than min
var object1 = {
    min: 5,
    max: 7
};

assert.deepStrictEqual(schema.validate(object1).error, undefined);

// invalid because max is not greater than min
var object2 = {
    min: 5,
    max: 5
};

assert.notStrictEqual(schema.validate(object2).error, undefined);

// invalid because max is not greater than min
var object3 = {
    min: 5,
    max: 3
};

assert.notStrictEqual(schema.validate(object3).error, undefined);

// valid as exception we want to allow -1
var object4 = {
    min: 5,
    max: -1
};

assert.deepStrictEqual(schema.validate(object4).error, undefined);
```

Comment: Could you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58933028/how-to-check-key-order-in-json-object-using-joi

Comment: That question cannot be resolved - you cannot ensure key order and manipulation of the object will end up working with the keys in order. It is highly unlikely that you would ever see object design like that. If the order is relevant, then perhaps you need to change the container to an array so it ends up like: `[{name: 'a'}, {name: 'c'}, {name: 'b'}]` - would that structure work for you?